# How can I use tabs in Mac Mail?

Tags: mail.app, macos, tabs

One of the new featuers in macOS Sierra are [tabs in more apps, including Mail](http://help.apple.com/macOS/Sierra/WN/?lang=en_GB#/tabs).

How do I use tabs in Mac Mail? Clicking "View", "Show tab bar" displays a bar with one tab, but I can't find a way to open a new tab.

Comment: New Tab is normally Cmd/T [don't have sierra to test]

Comment: Cmd-T opens the Font Selector in Mail :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For tabs to work in all situations, you need to enable them in System Preferences->Dock (set the appropriate option to "always"). Afterwards, you can (in Mail) select "File -- New window" or press <kbd>Opt-Cmd-N</kbd> to create a new tab.

Comment: This doesn't work, it opens a new window, and not a new tab.

Comment: It does work for me. Did you set the tab option to "Always" in System Preferences->Dock?

Comment: I had it set to "in full-screen only". Thanks.

Comment: In fact, you don't even have to have the tab bar open, that setting was enough to get it to work.

Comment: Is there a way to open a Tab _without_ setting the System Preference mentioned? I would like to be able to open a Tab in Mac Mail on demand, like I can in most/all web browsers.

Comment: @wodow Not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

If you hold down <kbd>option</kbd> while selecting *File > New Viewer Window*, a new viewer tab will be created regardless of any Dock System Preference setting.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if your question was ever answered but all you have to do is use "option-command-n" to create new tabs on the tab bar
the other shortcut, "command-n" just creates a new email window. if you hit again command-n it'll create a tab inside the new email window!
Both commands are shown under the "file" menu
However tabs will only open if you've selected "use tabs when opening new docs- always" under dock preferences (system preferences/dock)

Comment: I am curious why you think there is doubt about the question being answered, since there is an answer from a year ago from Patrix which is marked as an answer by the person who posted the question and has 10 next to it.  Does that answer not appear on the interface you are using to participate here??